# Ogre material scripts; how do I give a technique multiple lod_indexes?

Tags: graphics, glsl, ogre

I have an [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) material script that defines 4 rendering techniques. 1 using GLSL shaders, then 3 others that just use textures of different resolutions. 
I want to use the GLSL shader unconditionally if the graphics card supports it, and the other 3 textures depending on camera distance otherwise.

At the moment my script is;

```
material foo
{
lod_distances 1600 2000

technique shaders
{
     lod_index 0
     lod_index 1
     lod_index 2

     //various passes here
}

technique high_res {
     lod_index 0
     //various passes here
}

technique medium_res {
     lod_index 1
     //various passes here
}

technique low_res {
     lod_index 2
     //various passes here
}
```

#### Extra information

The [Ogre manual](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_15.html) says;

> Increasing indexes denote lower levels of detail
>
> You can (and often will) assign **more than one technique to the same LOD index**, what this means is that OGRE will pick 'the best technique of the ones listed at the same LOD index.
>
> OGRE determines which one is 'best' by which one is listed first.

Currently, on a machine supporting the GLSL version I am using, the script behaves as follows;

- Camera > 2000 : Shader technique
- Camera >1600 <= 2000 : Medium       // Here it is chosing my "texture" technique instead of the shader
- Camera <= 1600 : High               //

---

If I change the lod order in shader technique to

```
{
     lod_index 2
     lod_index 1
     lod_index 0
}
```

Only the latest lod_index is used.

---

If I change it to

```
lod_index 0 1 2
```

It shouts at me

```
 Compiler error: fewer parameters expected in foo.material(#): lod_index only supports 1 argument
```

So how do I specify a technique to have 3 lod_indexes?

Duplication works;

```
technique shaders
{
     lod_index 0
     //Shader passes here
}


technique shaders1
{
     lod_index 1
     //DUPLICATE of shader passses in lod 0
}


technique shaders2
{
     lod_index 2
     //DUPLICATE of shader passses in lod 0
}
```

...but it's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with different techniques for the different LOD values is indeed the correct one. A complete example file with material LOD usage, would look like this.

Note: You can of course change LOD strategy to fit your needs. All valid strategy values and their behavior are explained in the Ogre manual.

```
material testLOD
{
lod_strategy screen_ratio_pixel_count
lod_values 0.8 0.6 0.4 0.2

technique red10
{
    pass red
    {
        ambient 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        diffuse 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        specular 0.898039 0.898039 0.898039 1 20
        emissive 1 0 0 1
    }
}

technique green20
{
    lod_index 1
    pass green
    {
        ambient 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        diffuse 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        specular 0.898039 0.898039 0.898039 1 20
        emissive 0 1 0 1
    }
}

technique cyan100
{
    lod_index 2
    pass cyan
    {
        ambient 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        diffuse 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        specular 0.898039 0.898039 0.898039 1 20
        emissive 0 0.945098 0.980392 1
    }
}

technique blue200
{
    lod_index 3
    pass blue
    {
        ambient 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        diffuse 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        specular 0.898039 0.898039 0.898039 1 20
        emissive 0 0 1 1
    }
}

technique yellow1000
{
    lod_index 4
    pass yellow
    {
        ambient 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        diffuse 0.698039 0.698039 0.698039 1
        specular 0.898039 0.898039 0.898039 1 20
        emissive 1 1 0 1
    }
}
}
```